# Помгите , не понимаю почему всё время подсвечивается "print."

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
помгите , не могу написать ни какой код.

Comment: Вставляйте код в вопрос в виде текста. `print` тут не при чем. У вас синтаксическая ошибка в виде отсутствия двоеточия. `for i in range(2):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявление цикла должно заканчиваться двоеточием

```
for step in range(0, 20):
    print(step)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо сергей

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Огромое спасибо. Ты мне очень помог!@